# Bootstrapping on cluster level in python

Tags: python, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I need to bootstrap a statistic on cluster level in python.

I have multiple measurements per cluster and I want to perform a bootstrapped statistic (such as R-squared) based on sampling with replacement where the data is sampled per cluster, not per observation.

I tried doing this by hand using a loop of resamples on unique values of my cluster IDs.

[UDATE]
I was able to resample the IDs (using the loop iteration as the integer for the random number generation to get a reproducible result) and calculate the statistic, but it is so very slow.

So far so good(/bad?):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import resample
import statsmodels.api as sm


def bootstrap_rsquared(df, model_formula, time, cov_struct, dep_data, fam,
                       cluster='ID', n_resamples=10000):
    '''provides GEE pseudo-rsquareds from grouped bootstrap'''

    # get the unique IDs
    ids = np.unique(df[cluster].values)

    # prepare an empty list to save the bootstrapped statistics in
    rsqs = []
    
    # resample as often as needed
    for i in range(n_resamples - 1):

        # prepare empty dataset with correct column names to populate later
        dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

        # resample patient IDs from the unique IDs
        # using resample iteration count as random_state to get a reproducible result
        r = resample(ids, random_state=i)

        # populate the empty dataset with the resampled patients
        for p in r:
            dfs = pd.concat([dfs, df[df[cluster] == p]], axis=0)

        # fit model
        model = sm.GEE.from_formula(
            formula=model_formula,
            groups=cluster,
            data=dfs,
            time=time,
            cov_struct=cov_struct,
            dep_data=dep_data,
            family=fam)

        # calculate statistic
        rsq = model.fit().pseudo_rsquared()

        # append to the list of bootstrapped statistics
        rsqs.append(rsq)
    return rsqs
```

I need to find a faster way.
Any help or pointer appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while researching how to go about doing this myself, and couldn’t find any existing packages that seem to do what we’re looking for (at least in Python; I believe R has some), so I decided to go ahead and attempt it myself. I’m posting how I went about the clustered resampling in the hopes that it can help you as well. I did work off of your existing code, so you were off to a good start!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import resample

def cluster_resample(df, cluster):
  # get a list of unique ids in the original data
  ids = np.unique(df[cluster].values)
  # resample the ids with replacement (as in traditional bootstrapping, the resampled list of ids is the same length as the original number of ids)
  resampled_ids = resample(ids, replace=True, n_samples=len(ids))
  # get unique ids in the resampled list as well as number of times those ids appear in it
  unique_resampled_ids, counts_resampled_ids = np.unique(resampled_ids, return_counts=True)
  # zip together the above into a dictionary in order to easily lookup number of times we should repeat the data from each id
  resampled_ids_dict = dict(zip(unique_resampled_ids, counts_resampled_ids))
  # create a new empty dataframe in which to populate the data
  resampled_data = pd.DataFrame()
  # nested for loop that, for each unique id in the resampled list, looks up from the dictionary the "j" number of times it should appear, 
  # then appends all rows from the original dataframe that are associated with that id to the new dataframe "j" times
  for i in range(len(unique_resampled_ids)):
    for j in range(resampled_ids_dict[unique_resampled_ids[i]]):
      resampled_data = resampled_data.append(df[df[cluster]==unique_resampled_ids[i]])
  # this function returns the resampled data, so pass a variable name when calling the function (i.e. x = cluster_resample(df,'ID'))
  return resampled_data
```

Of course, this is only code to perform the resampling, not to execute your estimation procedure or obtain the bootstrapped statistic of interest, but I hope this helps you get started!

Comment: Hi @Josie,

Thanks for answering.

This is the code for one single resample on ID level?

Comment: BTW: I was able to implement a loop for bootstrapping the data on ID level myself, calculating and saving the statistic, but it ran so slow with the model fitting, that I gave up.

In R there is `group_bootstraps` in `rsample`, which is great. Really fast. You just need to supply the function for the statistic calculation. Sadly that does not work as fast using `reticulate` to use python functions in R. The low speed was prohibitive in my case.

Comment: Hi, I updated my attempt at a solution in the question. But it is way too slow. Have you made any headway?

Comment: Hey @SimonKrenn! Can you share a little more about the nature of your data? It is my understanding that, depending on the shape of your data and the model you're trying to fit, bootstrapping will be a time-consuming process. It took me approximately 3 hours to complete just 250 bootstrap rounds to estimate standard errors for a two-step procedure that begins with an XGBoost model for prediction, and ends with a fixed effects model using those predictions. I can update my answer, but would like to tailor it to your problem and test it on similarly-sized data.

Comment: Since your model is one-step, and without XGBoost, the training of which is the most time-intensive step of my procedure, I don't think it should take quite as long. Also, 10,000 rounds seems like it may be overkill. Will your bootstrapped statistic simply be the mean of the pseudo-R-squareds? If so, I would think it should converge far before 10,000.

Comment: Hi, my dataset is a slightly unbalanced nested time-series (multiple observations per date nested in period in subject) with about a total of 750 observations on 4 dates in 2 periods in 23 subjects and I want to calculate the BCa 95%-CIs and bias-corrected mean. 10000 iterations was just a sort of placeholder to indicate that I want it to run fast, so I can also reuse it for any type of cluster bootstrap later. 

I can really recommend R for bootstrapping. I just wanted to do it in python because of the GEE setup with multi-level nesting there.